# COUNTIF/MATCH after date

Tags: excel

What I'm essentially looking to do is be able to track to see how many refills our patients have received. I have a list of what was sent to the pharmacy, and what the pharmacy has returned. What I would like to do is fill in Column C on Sheet 1, which will track if the patient received any refills after their initial prescription fill. As below, patients can get more than one prescription in any month for different drugs. All I'm looking to do is count how many months they received something after their first month's fill.

In this example, Patient John would have 2 months of refills, Adam would have 0 (or No fills at all), Bob would have 0 refills, and Phil would have 1 refill month.

Thanks!

```
Sheet 1
A       B       C
Date    Patient Refills
1/1/18  John
1/2/18  Adam
1/3/18  Bob
1/4/18  Phil

Sheet 2
A           B           C
Date Filled Patient     Prescription
1/10/18     John        Drug A
1/10/18     John        Drug B
1/12/18     Bob         Drug A
1/12/18     Bob         Drug B
1/12/18     Bob         Drug C
1/13/18     Phil        Drug C
2/10/18     John        Drug A
2/10/18     John        Drug B
2/13/18     Phil        Drug C
2/13/18     Phil        Drug D
3/10/18     John        Drug A
```

Comment: You could get the right answer just by counting the number of unique dates for each patient and subtracting 1. What if John had drug A on 10th Jan, drug B on 11th Jan, repeat of drug A on 10th Feb and drug B on 11th Feb though? I guess that's still one top-up so you want it per month as you say. Could still run into problems where it goes over a month boundary (say 31st Jan then 1st March? That's really tricky - need to set some sort of window and probably getting into VBA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here are a couple of formulas which go some way towards addressing the problem.

The first one is just a standard formula for counting the number of different dates for John which can be pulled down for the other patients

```
=MAX(SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B$2:B$12=F2,A$2:A$12),$A$2:$A$12)>0))-1,0)
```

The next one is counting the number of different *months* for John, and can also be pulled down for the other patients. In this case, two different dates for the same patient in the same month would be counted as one:

```
=MAX(SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B$2:B$12=F2,MONTH(A$2:A$12)),MONTH($A$2:$A$12))>0))-1,0)
```

Both these have to be entered as array formulas using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

I have changed the data slightly to show the difference between the two formulas

[image]

Note that these formulas have limitations as mentioned in the comment, where the prescription dates might split across the end of a month in your real data, or if they span multiple years, in which case you would need a more sophisticated approach.

Answer (score 0):

on sheet1, column c2
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!A:A,">" & A2)

Comment: This returns 5, not 2.

Comment: Will need to play with counting unique months after the first month in format YYYYMM